# mediaelement not displaying player in ie8

Tags: internet-explorer-8, mediaelement.js

I have set up a mediaelement player that is being built dynamically using version 2.1.7.

Everything looks and works great in iOS, firefox, chrome, safari, as well as ie7 & ie9.  But ie8 is not loading any flash or media.  It displays blank. Please see: http://chadstrat.com/index.php?cID=126.

I don't see any js conflicts or any debug errors.

Any help would be very seriously appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

I had this issue and found I needed to move jQuery to the top of the page from the bottom. This was on http://hanselminutes.com.